# Is DNS address included in ARP address table?

Tags: arp, dns, windows

I have DNS server address 8.8.8.8 . Is it supposed to be included in my ARP table when i execute `arp -a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. ARP is used to resolve an IP address to the MAC address required for delivery *within your local network* = L2 segment = IPv4 subnet.  MAC addresses outside your local network are meaningless. Also, ARP is only used in MAC-based networks - not all networks are.

Packets for destinations outside the local subnet are sent to the gateway determined by the local routing table. If the subnet runs on a MAC-based network then that gateway's MAC address is resolved by ARP for IPv4 and used as destination for the frame encapsulating the IP packet (which in turn encapsulates the UDP datagram carrying your DNS request).